# How to use correctly name variable in file upload form data? How to upload file with python script?

Tags: python, file, upload

I can upload a file via a browser using this code:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"     action="domen.com/file.php">
<input type="file" name="var_name">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

But I can't upload a file with this script

```
values = {'name':'var_name','type':'filename'}
files = {'file': open('uploadfile.php', 'rb')}
res1 = requests.post('domen.com/file.php', files = files, data = values, timeout = timeouts)
```

Why?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What happens when you try to upload the file using `requests`?

Comment: Nothing happens, the file is not uploaded, but with browser is uploaded.

Comment: `html` upload a file, `script` push a file. `upload != push`, upload using a additional socket connection for reading stream ! you send a `StringIO` object not a file. Try send file_object as string if you have small size file.

Comment: Can you show what's the difference between my code and code as string?

Comment: The answer is: files = {var_name: open('/file.php', 'rb')}